# Make night mode on fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I need a option for night mode in a fullcalendar(adamshaw) agenda week view, that is it show the night time only for example 8pm to 8am (from top 8pm to continue until 8am) is there any help regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [businessHours](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/businessHours/) on the fullcalendar docs. You can specify start and end times and optionally days of the week.

```
{
    start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
    end: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)

    dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
    // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
    // (Monday-Thursday in this example)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy:

```
        minTime: "20:00",
        maxTime: "32:00",
```

Use this in fullCalendar options when creating it.